# $(body) inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

Let's say I have an iframe page (iframe.html). Inside this page, I have a script
$(body) or $(document). Now I wanted to understand what does it represent ?

Does it refer to iframes body or the main page body ? If it represnts the main page, how do I make it refer to the iframe  ?

Comment: This would have been trivial to test yourself.

Comment: You mean `$(document.body)`... or better: `$('body')`... Just `$(body)` won't work (unless you explicitly define a variable with that name and put `document.body` inside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('body')` and `document` refer to those of the `iframe`'s own document.

- Within the encapsulating page, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) to access the `iframe` contents with jQuery selectors.
- Within the `iframe`, `window.parent` may refer to the encapsulating page.

Answer (score 5):

To find element withing `iframe` try this

```
$("iframeSelector").contents().find("#element_in_iframe").click(function(e){ 
   alert(1); 
 });
```

Comment: @Diana - I think this is what you might possibly be looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

**If you are inside the iframe:**

`$(body)` and `$(document)` will refer to the document contained within the iframe, and will typically be ignorant of the parent page.

**If you need to access the outer page from within the iframe:**

You can use `window.parent` to access the page that contains the iframe if necessary.

Comment: I am asking this, as the following code is not working; 
$("#element_in_iframe").click(function(e){
alert(1);
     });

Comment: For this to work - you will need to wire that event within the page that is contained within the iframe. So if you created that event within the load of the "iframe page" it should fire with no problem.

Comment: @Diana Does the page in the IFRAME have jQuery?

Comment: @Diana: They are two _separate_ documents.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the body in side your IFRAME.  jQuery will always work in the context of the current (first parent) document.  If you want to specify a different context, that is when you use jquery's context arguments.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

jQuery( selector, [context] )
selector:  A string containing a selector expression
context:  A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

So `$('body')` refers to the document inside your IFRAME and can be thought to be implicitly doing:  `$('body', document);`  To get the document of the parent frame you would have to do something like `$('body', parent.document);`.  This would of course be subject to cross-frame restrictions, depending on how you're doing this.